# How to return multiple responses from "doInBackground"

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this code in which i can retrieve data from already prepared URL and display it in my MPAndroid chart, but i would like to add another line with data that is retrieved from another URL:

```
inner class WeatherTaskTempLine : AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
    override fun onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute()
    }
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): String? {
        var response:String?
        try{

            val tempData = uriToday.build().toString()
            response = URL(tempData).readText(
                    Charsets.UTF_8
            )

        }catch (e: Exception){
            response = null
        }
        return response
    }
    override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        try {
            val yVals = ArrayList<Entry>()
            val xVals = ArrayList<Entry>()
            /* Extracting JSON returns from the API */
            val jsonTemperatureData = JSONArray(result)
            for (i in 0 until jsonTemperatureData.length()) {
                val item = jsonTemperatureData.getJSONObject(i)
                val reading_temperature = item.getString("reading_temperature")
                val hour = item.getString("hour")
                yVals.add(Entry(hour.toFloat(), reading_temperature.toFloat(), i.toString()))
                //xVals.add(Entry(hour.toFloat(), reading_humidity.toFloat(), i.toString()))
            }
            val set1: LineDataSet
            set1 = LineDataSet(yVals, "Temperatura")
            val set2: LineDataSet
            set2 = LineDataSet(xVals, "Temperatura jucer")

            val dataSets = ArrayList<ILineDataSet>()
            dataSets.add(set1)
            dataSets.add(set2)
            val data = LineData(dataSets)
            chart1.setData(data)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
        }
    }
}
```

I can get JSON data from:

```
           `val tempData = uriToday.build().toString()
            response = URL(tempData).readText(Charsets.UTF_8)`
```

But i would also like to pass

```
   val tempData = uriArchive.build().toString()
            response = URL(tempData).readText(
                    Charsets.UTF_8
            )
```

So i can iterate through that data in another loop like this one and set another line to my MPAndroidChart:

```
  for (i in 0 until jsonTemperatureData.length()) {
  }
```

If this is not a correct way of doing this, what would it be?

Comment: id highly recommend you to learn why we use AsyncTask<String, Void, String> these generic types while declaring our Asynctask, where they are used. And since they are generic you can use just about put every class in these 3 positions

Answer (score 2):

You can return other data types from your AsyncTask class other than just a string.

For Example You can return an ArrayList of Strings

```
inner class WeatherTaskTempLine : AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>>() {
```

This would allow you to return multiple items of data from `doInBackground`

Note you need to adjust the result object type in `onPostExecute` as well `doInBackground` return type.